I Even mocking a method of a class correctly, it still asks for validation credentials, even if the function is mocked
I'm trying to mock a method called getHouseFullInfo, of a class, it connects to DynamoDb to access data, and even mocking DynamoDBClient and DynamoDBDocumentClient which are the dependencies of this method, when running the test, I end up getting the credentials error invalid or without credentials, even though this error should not appear since the function is mocked.
import * as AWSMock from 'aws-sdk-mock';
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import { HouseManager } from '../../lambda/house_manager';
import { Logger } from '@aws-lambda-powertools/logger';
import { QueryInput, DynamoDBClient } from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb';
import { DynamoDBDocumentClient } from '@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb';

// Assuming AWSMock has a way to mock AWS SDK v3 or using jest for mocking
jest.mock('@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb');
jest.mock('@aws-lambda-powertools/logger');
jest.mock('@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb')


const loggerMock = { info: jest.fn(), error: jest.fn() } as unknown as Logger;
new Logger();


describe('HouseManager', () => {
    let houseManager: HouseManager;
    let ddb: DynamoDBDocumentClient;

    beforeAll(() => {
        const ddbClient = new DynamoDBClient({
            region: 'us-east-1', // Choose an appropriate region
            credentials: {
                accessKeyId: 'testing',
                secretAccessKey: 'testing',
                sessionToken: 'testing'
            }
        });
        ddb = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(ddbClient, {
            // Automatically remove undefined values
            marshallOptions: {
                removeUndefinedValues: true
            },
        });

        // Set the AWS SDK instance for mocking
        AWSMock.setSDKInstance(AWS);

        // Set the AWS Mock Response
        const mockResponse = {
            Items: [{
                PK: `HOUSE#aa231eb4-2927-46f4-a625-f6167ebc019c`,
                data: {
                    id: 'aa231eb4-2927-46f4-a625-f6167ebc019c',
                    name: "Jest Test House",
                    description: "This an automated test house for JEST.",
                    owner: "JEST-0001",
                    priceDetails: {
                        dailyPriceAvg: 300,
                        guestFee: 50,
                        petFee: 20,
                        priceCalendar: "c_f5f4ec60eb80b6b4c4824eeaa569da58f99eaa103cc0b0555ade5ae7fd746a0d@group.calendar.google.com"
                    },
                    location: {
                        active: true,
                        cityId: "BSB",
                        cityName: "Brasília",
                        countryId: "BR",
                        countryName: "Brasil",
                        stateId: "DF",
                        stateName: "Distrito Federal"
                    },
                    active: true
                },
                entity: 'HOUSE'
            }]
        };
        AWSMock.mock('DynamoDB.DocumentClient', 'query', (params: QueryInput, callback: any) => {
            callback(null, mockResponse);
        });
    });

    afterAll(() => {
        AWSMock.restore();
    });
    beforeEach(() => {
        houseManager = new HouseManager();
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    describe('getHouseFullInfo', () => {
        it('should call the logger info method', () => {
            loggerMock.info('test');
            expect(loggerMock.info).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test');
        });

        it('successfully retrieves house full information', async () => {
            const houseId = 'aa231eb4-2927-46f4-a625-f6167ebc019c';

            const result = await houseManager.getHouseFullInfo(houseId);
            expect(result).toBeDefined();
            expect(result.id).toEqual(houseId);
            expect(result.location.cityName).toEqual('Brasília');
            expect(result.description).toEqual("This an automated test house for JEST.");
            expect(loggerMock.info).toHaveBeenCalled();
        }, 10000); // Timeout set to 10 seconds;
    });
});


I tried redoing a function with the same dependencies in another file and it worked. However, when it comes to HouserManager, I end up falling into the same hole, I've tried mocking it in different ways, but without success.

I don't think we can answer this without a rough outline of your lambda. In particular, does it initialize any global entities? Edit: Oh, you're using aws-sdk-mock. Hmm, if you check the docs for that package, it mocks more simply than you're doing here. Maybe try that approach?

Yes. I already made a simpler mocking code, but this was the standard code given to me by the company. But even so, I have already mocked this method in every way, but without success.
